# bosun with influxdb valid result

Tags: influxdb, bosun

Is there a simple test to make sure I have proper influxdb communication?

My configuration looks like this

```
influxHost = influxhost:8086
smtpHost = mail:25
emailFrom = user@domain.com


template cpu {
    body = `Alert definition:
        Name: {{.Alert.Name}}
Crit: {{.Alert.Crit}}

Tags:{{range $k, $v := .Tags}}
     {{$k}}: {{$v}}{{end}}
     `
         subject = cpu idle at {{.Alert.Vars.q | .E}} on {{.Tags.host}}
}



notification default {
    email = user@domain.com
        next = default
        timeout = 1h
}
```

On the bosun expression evulator I am doing

```
influx("db",'''SELECT mean(usage_idle) FROM "cpu"  group by host''',"10m","","2m")
```

I keep getting

```
influx: did not get a valid result from InfluxDB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct influx database and that there is data in the specified time range. I usually try from the admin site first:

[image: influxdb admin site]

Then insert the query into the influx(...) expression

[image: bosun influx expression]

Bosun will add the time conditions to the WHERE and GROUP BY clauses as needed, so the full influxql generated should be something like:

```
SELECT mean(usage_idle) FROM cpu WHERE time >= '2016-12-07 20:00:00' AND time <= '2016-12-07 20:10:00' GROUP BY host,time(2m)
```

If it still doesn't work try `SELECT * FROM cpu` on the admin page to see what data is in the table (telegraf has gone thru a few changes). Also note in the recent versions you probably want to add `cpu = 'cpu-total'` to the WHERE clause to get the overall average.

Comment: You absolutely rock! Works now!